# Sorting Array with specific order in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort an array in specific order in swiftUI

```
let list = ["A","B","A1","C","B1","AA"]
```

I tried :

```
let sortedList = list.sorted{ $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
// Output : sortedList = ["A","A1","AA","B","B1","C"]
```

And also

```
let sortedList = list.sorted{ $0.parcoursNom < $1.parcoursNom }
// Output : sortedList = ["A","A1","AA","B","B1","C"]
```

Expected :

```
sortedList = ["A","AA","B","C","A1","B1"]
```

If finish by a number then at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom sort function for this

```
let sortedList = list.sorted {
    switch ($0.last!.isNumber, $1.last!.isNumber) {
    case (true, false):
        return false
    case (false, true):
        return true
    default:
        return $0 < $1
    }
}
```

If you need to handle possible empty strings then add two `case` for that and we can avoid the forced unwrap

```
let sortedList = list.sorted {
    switch ($0.last?.isNumber, $1.last?.isNumber) {
    case (true, false):
        return false
    case (false, true):
        return true
    case (nil, _):
        return false
    case (_, nil):
        return true
    default:
        return $0 < $1
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest extracting this `switch` out to a function, and writing tests that exercise all 9 possible combinations of `true`/`false`/`nil`. It's surprisingly challenging to write case-by-case comparators that are sound (i.e. correct in that they provide a consistent partial ordering, as explained in the documentation)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, especially when sorting tuples, it's helpful to be able to "make Bools Comparable". That way, you can give sorting priority using tuple positioning.

```swift
["A","B","A1","C","B1","AA"].sorted {
  let comparables = { (string: String) in
    ( (string.last?.isNumber ?? false).comparable,
      string
    )
  }

  return comparables($0) < comparables($1)
}
```

```swift
public extension Bool {
  /// A way to compare `Bool`s.
  ///
  /// Note: `false` is "less than" `true`.
  enum Comparable: CaseIterable, Swift.Comparable {
    case `false`, `true`
  }

  /// Make a `Bool` `Comparable`, with `false` being "less than" `true`.
  var comparable: Comparable { .init(booleanLiteral: self) }
}

extension Bool.Comparable: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
  public init(booleanLiteral value: Bool) {
    self = value ? .true : .false
  }
}
```

Comment: Why CaseIterable?

Comment: It's not used here, but it's something that I think this type, and `Bool` itself, ought to have.

Comment: Why not simply `extension Bool: Comparable {` `public static func < (lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {` `!lhs || rhs` `}` `}`?

Comment: and then sort by `{ ($0.last?.isNumber == true, $0) < ($1.last?.isNumber == true, $1)
}`

Comment: My vote up goes for the idea of making Bool Comparable and comparing a tuple. The implementation IMO is much more complex than it should be

Comment: `Bool` shouldn't always be `Comparable`. If that made sense, it would be in the standard library. It's only helpful to think of it that way *sometimes*. If you've got a better method for that, I'm all ears!

Comment: If you are concerned about making it comparable just create a computed property to return a value zero for false and one for true and sort is value `extension Bool { var value: Int { self ? 1 : 0 } }`
`(($0.last?.isNumber == true).value, $0) < (($1.last?.isNumber == true).value, $1) `

Comment: That’s akin to saying to use a String for every type, instead of an actual type. It’s not meaningful without commenting every usage.